# Incorrect proof: $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to proove this expression but I got a fault but I don't find it. [image: failed proof]

(Sorry but StackExchange wasn't able to compile my Latex code because of some format commands so I took a picture)

Hope somebody can help me to find my fault!!

Comment: The error is in the second line. The complement of 
$$x \in A \,\,\text{AND}\,\, x \in B
$$ 
is 
$$x \not\in A \,\,\text{OR}\,\, x \not\in B
$$

Comment: Second like should have $x \notin A \cup x \notin B$. Be careful with DeMorgan's Laws